# How to update user data Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to increment score by 1 when user clicks a button, but value of score is not updated. When I updated it manually from Firebase console it updates. I don't know what the problem is. Can anyone help me, please?

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == add) {
        score++;
        databaseReference1 = databaseReference.child("score");
        databaseReference1.setValue(String.valueOf(score));
        databaseReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                textView_earning.setText(score + " ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Move the addValueEventListener part outside onClick into onCreate/onStart, there is no need to call it each time you press the button because it already updates in realtime.

Comment: please can we have a snap of your firebase please

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the value event listener before changing the value.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == add) {
        score++;
        ref1 = ref.child("score");
        ref1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                textView_earning.setText(score + " ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        ref1.setValue(String.valueOf(score));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place `addValueEventListener` inside `onClick()`, you'll end up attaching one more listener into `databaseReference1` every time the button clicked. It is not a best practice as you'll face more kind of problem if it is clicked multiple time.

You should place `addValueEventListener` somewhere else, like (not limited to) in `activity`'s `onCreate()` method:

```
... onCreate(...) {
    databaseReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

And place score variable where it is easily got, and update it inside `onDataChange()` (for this example, I place it on `scoreValue`:

```
private String scoreValue;
... onCreate(...) {
    databaseReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            scoreValue = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)
        }
...
```

And then inside `onClick()`, you just need to get `scoreValue`, increment it by 1, and save the value:

```
... onClick() {
    if (view == add) {
        scoreValue++;
        databaseReference.child("score").setValue(scoreValue);
    }
}
```

Then `setValue(scoreValue)` will update the value at the online database, and trigger `onDataChange()`. So don't worry if the value is changed online, `scoreValue` will always have updated value.

Hope this helps.

> Note: all of this consider `score` value is at `(your databaseReference
>   path)\score`

Answer (score 0):

you can use **updateChildren** for update single values.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);

    HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm.put("score",  score++);
    ref.child("YOUR_ROOT_NODE")
               .updateChildren(hm);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for your answer,the problem is fixed,actually i make a stupid mistake as i do not set on click listener on my button